# Getting Asterisk PBX to do SIP URI dialling properly?

Tags: sip, asterisk

I've installed AsteriskNOW in a VM and I'm having a hard time getting calls from the PBX to head outbound to another SIP address on the SIP2SIP network I use for occasional testing purposes. However, attempting to dial ANY SIP URI from one of the endpoints associated with the PBX results in a Service Unavailable error on the client used, and produces the following error in the Asterisk CLI:

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
   -- Executing [destuname@clients:1] Verbose("SIP/sourceuname-00000000", ""), in 
      new stack
   -- Executing [destuname@clients:1] Dial("SIP/sourceuname-00000000", "SIP/destuname
      @sip2sip.info") in new stack
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
   -- Called SIP/destuname@sip2sip.info
   -- Got SIP response 500 "Server Internal Error" back from 81.23.228.129:5060
   -- SIP/sip2sip.info-00000001 is circuit-busy
== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
   -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/sourceusername-00000000' status is 'CONGESTION'
```

All the endpoints on my network are contained in a context aptly named clients; the line in extensions.conf to faciliate dialling of SIP URIs is:

```
exten => _[0-9a-zA-Z].,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@${SIPDOMAIN})
```

What can I do in order to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need check sip debug

Very likly url is ok, you have issue on other side

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```